# VBA function to find cell value within range

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner vba user.

I'm trying to create a function that will allocate the correct `client_id` in cell `C2:C6`, using the `House` and the `Date` values.

[image]

One `House` could have had multiple `client_ids` over time, so I need to allocate the correct `client_id` based on the `Joining Date`.

The function needs to find all instances where the `House` value is the same in the range `A9:C13`.

Below is the desired outcome:

[image]

The first step is setting the range, and then looping through this range for column `B` to find all instances where the house number matched the value in this column.

If I set the known range:

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Data!A10:C13")
```

How do I loop over this range for column `B`?

Comment: this can be done with a formula.

Comment: I don't understand why you put in C1 0055G11. The date has no Joining Date match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing to properly reference a parent worksheet, run:

```
range("c2:c6").formula = "=INDEX(A$10:A$13, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($1:$4)/((C$10:C$13<A2)*(B$10:B$13=B2)), 1))"
```

This formula does depend on ascending join dates (per each house) in C10:C13.

[image]